# Thin client vs. PC for RDP-only connection

Tags: windows, cloud, remote-desktop, thin-client

Context : I'm switching my whole desktop environment, and after many thoughts, I'm going with a Virtual Machine hosted on a Google Cloud (Win Server 2016)

The server is a "Single User" machine, that will receive an RDP connection. The terminal must allow :

- Dual Monitor
- Port forwarding (USB, Local Printer)

What would be the best option :

- Buying a refurbished PC, and use Native Remote Desktop
- A proper thin client that supports RDP
- Raspberry Pi 3 (Linux with a RDP session)

I'm looking for the best performance for general work (no 3d, Cad, ect.)

Answer (score 0):

I used for this purpose a raspberry pi with Raspbian. For the remote sessions I use Vinagre.

It works very well and it's cheap.

But I am not sure about multimonitor and port forwarding...

Comment: I've researched a little about dual monitor on Raspberry Pi 3, and it's possible through a Display Extender (USB to DVI) and a script.

Do you notice performance drops with Vinagre in the ''networking'' aspect? I know it's a lit depends of the server's quality and ressources, but on a general RDP session through a MacBook Air on 2 screens, I have no performance drop.

Answer (score -3):

In your scenario, where you're setting up a virtual machine (VM) on Google Cloud with Windows Server 2016 and you want to have dual monitors and support for port forwarding (USB, Local Printer), you have a few options to consider:

1. Refurbished PC with Native Remote Desktop:

   - This option can provide good performance since you're using a dedicated physical machine.
   - Dual monitor support and local device redirection can work well with a native RDP client.
   - However, you'll need to ensure the refurbished PC has the necessary hardware specifications for your needs.
2. Thin Client with RDP Support:

   - Thin clients are designed to efficiently run RDP sessions and can be a cost-effective solution.
   - Some thin clients offer support for dual monitors and local device redirection.
   - Check the specifications of the thin client to ensure it meets your requirements.
3. Raspberry Pi 3 with Linux and RDP:

   - Raspberry Pi 3 can be a budget-friendly option, but its performance may not be as robust as a dedicated PC or thin client.
   - It may support dual monitors, but performance can vary based on the specific Raspberry Pi model and the demands of your virtual machine.
   - Raspberry Pi's USB and local printer support can be limited, and you may need additional configuration or software.

For the best performance for general work without 3D or CAD requirements, here's a breakdown:

- If budget is not a concern, a refurbished PC with a native Remote Desktop client may offer the best overall performance due to its more powerful hardware.
- A good-quality thin client with RDP support can be a balance between cost and performance.
- Raspberry Pi 3 can be a cost-effective solution but may have limitations in terms of performance and device support.

Ultimately, the choice depends on your specific requirements, budget, and performance expectations. Consider the performance capabilities of each option and ensure it aligns with your needs for dual monitors and local device redirection while also factoring in the cost of the hardware.

Comment: did you use any AI at all to write any part of this answer?